# If size of each conjugacy class is atmost $2$ then $G'\leq Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question is :

Show that if the size of each conjugacy class of a group $G$ is at most $2$ Then $G'\subseteq Z(G)$.

Suppose size of conjugacy class of an element $g\in G$ is $1$ i.e., $ngn^{-1}=g$ for all $n\in G$ i.e., $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}=1\in Z(G)$. So, $ngn^{-1}g^{-1}\in Z(G)$ for all $n\in G$ and $g\in G$ with conjugacy class having only one element.

i am stuck with the case of elements having conjugacy class order 2.

I would be thankful if someone can give hint for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The size of the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ is equal to $[G : C_G(x)]$.

Comment: This was my first thought when I saw the question, and it did not directly lead me anywhere. Maybe you could elaborate on the hint?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Either $[G : C_G(x)] = 1$ or $[G : C_G(x)] = 2$. In both cases you can prove that $G' \leq C_G(x)$, so $G'$ centralizes every element of $G$. It helps to remember that subgroups of index $2$ are normal

Comment: @mikko korhonen : I see that size of conjugacy class of $x\in G$ is $[G : C_G(x)]$ i.e., $C_G(x)$ is normal.. and then??

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen : I have written my comment before reading yours... :). I see that $C_G(x)$ is normal but why does that mply $G'\leq C_G(x)$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: If $G/N$ is abelian, then $G' \leq N$. Groups of order $2$ are abelian.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen oh, yes. Thank you. :)

Comment: So, we see that $G'\leq C_G(x)$ for all $x\in G$ and as $Z(G)=\cap_{x\in G}C_G(x)$ we see that $G'\leq \cap_{x\in G}C_G(x)=Z(G)$. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Not sure how I missed that. Very nice way to do this.